# List of abstract object that requires instanceof and casting

Tags: java, design-patterns

I Have a class which calls a method, that will convert an excel file, and each sheet will be a DTO, and returns a list containing those DTOs

```
List<Object> dtos = convertExcelToDTO();
```

Inside this list, I have 9 DTOs.
But I need to get some attributes individually from each DTO.
At first, I could iterate that list doing a instanceof and casting to my specific DTO.
But I don't like this approach, and I'm struggling to improve it.
I tried and created an Abstract class called AbstractDTO, where all DTOs would extend it, and implement a method:

```
public abstract AbstractDTO getDTOType();
```

And the childs would implement:

```
@Override
public myDTO getDTOType() {
    return this;
}
```

And my list would be:

```
List<AbstractDTO> dtos = convertExcelToDTO();
```

But since the list of AbstractDTO type, the return will not be specific:

```
MyDTO dtoType = dtos.get(0).getDTOType(); // Doesnt compile
```

How can I iterate that list of Object/AbstractDTO, getting the specific dto class, without using instanceof, and maybe without casting? Is it possible?

By the way, I can't change the service to make individual calls for each DTO, because DTO numbers also depends on some arguments, and not only sheets number.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot avoid casting. You can use generics wildcard to solve the compile error. from the example code, I see that the order of DTOs in the list determines their concrete type. (is that correct?) so this should work:

```
List<? extends AbstractDTO> dtos = convertExcelToDTO();
MyDTO MyDTO = (MyDTO)dtos.get(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I ended up refactoring a bit the code to be able to get specific dtos per call...but maybe I'll refactor again using your idea.
Oh, and no, the order doesn't determine the dto type.